# How to use ScrollView inside RelativeLayout for Android?

Tags: java, android

- I am trying to add multiple TextViews dynamically to my RelativeLayout, and while this works, when the screen is filled with text, the scrolling does not kick in. Any ideas on how to make it scroll-able?
- It looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pud8g.jpg (also, while we're at it, how can I make the fab buttons be 0% transparent? i dont understand why u can see through the buttons the text) :(
- One way I tried to make it work was to make ScrollView the parent layout (but it would push my buttons on the top side of the screen), but scrolling worked (but idk how to push the buttons back on the bottom of the screen) and also tried other answers found on Stackoverflow, but none seemed to help me. I tried the whole day to fix this goddamn Scroll.

XML Code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".PostDataFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewId">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/row0"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:text="TextView" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>


    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayoutId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fabtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/baseline_add_white_24dp"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/pictureLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:text="New Picture" />

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fabPicture"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/baseline_insert_photo_white_24dp"
                app:fabSize="mini" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/textLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:text="New Paragraph" />

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fabText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/baseline_notes_white_24dp"
                app:fabSize="mini"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="144dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="320dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Java Fragment File (inside onCreateView):

```
parentRLayout = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutId);
```

Inside a button listener in the Java Fragment File -> When a button is 
clicked, then text is added into a dialog, and when fabText button is 
clicked and text is added on the screen -> following line of code: 
                             `parentRLayout.addView(createNewTextView(paragraphText.getText().toString(), 0, 5, 5));`

```
//Function that returns a TextView (in the same Java Fragment Class)
TextView createNewTextView(String text, int alignment, int margin, int padding){
    TextView newDynamicTextView = new TextView(getActivity());

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, currentId);
    newDynamicTextView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    newDynamicTextView.setId(TextView.generateViewId());

    currentId = newDynamicTextView.getId();
    Log.d("currentId", ""+currentId);
    newDynamicTextView.setText(text);

    Log.d("newDynamic:", newDynamicTextView.getText().toString());
    return newDynamicTextView;
}
```

**EDIT:**
I have managed to make it work. The idea is to have the CoordinatorLayout as the root(parent) layout and inside it a ScrollView that has inside a RelativeLayout. The buttons are outside the ScrollView (under it) so they don't scroll.

Answer (score 0):

My one cent.

*It looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pud8g.jpg (also, while we're at it, how can I make the fab buttons be 0% transparent? i dont understand why u can see through the buttons the text)*

Please take note that views are drawn based on their order in your xml layout.

> Because the tree is traversed pre-order, this means that parents will
>   be drawn before (i.e., behind) their children, with siblings drawn in
>   the order they appear in the tree.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws